# How to declare c++ pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

```
BIRDREADING *bird_data;
bird_data = &frame.reading[i];
```

How to declare such in C#?

update1:

i want To call a C++ DLL/lib or to rewrite in C#. Actually i try to solve my own question on this link.[Use a variable directly(data return are same in an array) or with pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223703/use-a-variable-directlydata-return-are-same-in-an-array-or-with-pointer)
Try my luck to solve the question after i convert above into c#

Comment: What for?  To call a C++ DLL/lib or to rewrite in C#?

Comment: You don't use pointers in C#. Would you care to add more background to the question.

Comment: HenkHolterman@ yes i want  To call a C++ DLL/lib or to rewrite in C#.

Actually i try to solve my own question on this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223703/use-a-variable-directlydata-return-are-same-in-an-array-or-with-pointer. Try my luck to solve the question after i convert above into c#.

Comment: there are a gazillion questions on stack overflow asking about these birds and how to pinvoke them. Why don't you search them all out. I'm sure lots have been asked by users other than you. If you are new with c# why don't you start by learning the basics?

Comment: currently on stack overflow i only can found a user asking about it Tom Wright. It is really very limited source/information about this hardware especially code with c sharp.

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the information you want

Answer (score 4):

In c# you can declare pointers which called as unsafe programming.

Example :

```
unsafe {
            int iData = 10;
            int* pData = &iData;
            Console.WriteLine("Data is " + iData);
            Console.WriteLine("Address is " + (int)pData );
        }
```

Check this article : [Writing Unsafe code using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/unsafe.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`type* identifier;`

It depends, will BIRDREADING be a reference type?

You can't declare pointers to reference types from [Pointer Types (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Any of the following types may be a
>   pointer type:
>   sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, or bool.
>   Any enum type.
>   Any pointer type.
>   Any user-defined struct type that contains fields of unmanaged types only.

So for your example, giving that BIRDREADING statisifies the above

```
BIRDREADING *bird_data;
```

Also, what do you want to use the pointer for? Are you sure you need a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

If `BIRDREADING` is a class it is a pointer by definition and you don't need to do anything special:

```
BIRDREADING bird_data;
bird_data = frame.reading[i];
```

If it's a struct then getting its poiner depends on the context.

Comment: yes BIRDREADING  is a struct, sorry i'm still new in csharp. what u mean"it's a struct then getting its poiner depends on the context."